# Is there any benefit to implementing RealmModel instead of extending RealmObject in Realm?

Tags: java, android, realm

In `Realm`, in order for an object to be able to be persisted it must either implement `RealmModel` or extend `RealmObject`. Are there benefits to using one over the other?

All it says in the [realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface) is:

> An alternative to extending the RealmObject base class is implementing the RealmModel interface and adding the @RealmClass annotation.

> All methods available on RealmObject are then available through static methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Considering that [extending any non-`RealmObject` classes is not possible even if you're implementing `RealmModel` and adding `@RealmClass`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2716#issuecomment-219640616), in my opinion you just get additional complexity by forcing yourself to use for example `RealmObject.isValid(realmObject)` instead of `realmObject.isValid()` that you get naturally for free using `extends RealmObject`.

So no, you should stick to extending `RealmObject`. Using `implements RealmModel` gives you no additional benefit.

Comment: Currently the only benefit with `RealmModel` is that you can have your own custom `isValid()`. If you extend `RealmObject` you cannot have such a method in your own class.

Comment: I guess that goes for `isManaged()` and `isLoaded()` (and `deleteFromRealm()`) too.

Comment: Yes, it applies to all the methods on `RealmObject` as we made all of them `final`.

Comment: Isn't there an advantage that you can use a Parcelable with RealModel aswell.

Comment: Worth mentioning that with Kotlin you can import `import io.realm.kotlin.*` which gives you all those methods on `RealmModel` which are on `RealmObject`. So e.g. you can `myModel.deleteFromRealm()`.

Comment: Yup! Those did not exist in Sep 2016, but they were definitely added since 4.3.0 (2017-12-05)